# How to detect whether the scroll view is scrollable or not in android?

Tags: android, scrollview

As we know that scroll view will scroll,if the child view height is more than the height of the scroll view...if the child view height is small or equal to height of the scroll view height then the scroll view is not scrollable.
Is there any way to detect whether the scroll view is scrollable or not?.

```
<com.customerfirst.utilities.LockableVerScroll
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_questions"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:splitMotionEvents="false"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                 >
            </LinearLayout>
        </com.customerfirst.utilities.LockableVerScroll>
```

need help thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18574328/1584654

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if ScrollView is higher than screen / scrollable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572790/check-if-scrollview-is-higher-than-screen-scrollable)

Comment: getting height of my scroll view returns 0,i called it after the whole scroll view is created.I have no idea why it is showing 0.

Comment: may it because i have given my scroll view height as fill parent
?