# How to get nestedscrollview can scroll or not?

Tags: java, android, scroll, android-nestedscrollview

Is there any way to get that **nestedscrollview** have some element for scroll or not. I want to put some down arrow indication in app in which user will indicate through a down arrow if it's having item for scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Inpired by code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18574328/7384780. You can do it like this.

```
NestedScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);
int childHeight = ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrollContent)).getHeight();
boolean isScrollable = scrollView.getHeight() < childHeight + 
scrollView.getPaddingTop() + scrollView.getPaddingBottom();
```